# Python Calling def in class WITHOUT __init__

Tags: python, function, class, initialization

The ultimate goal is to have this run without **inti**(self, ...)

This code prints two numbers from the list if it equals the target
nums is set as [2,4,6,7] and target as 11

I have an issue printing my ans. Been trying many printing lines, and this is my last line **print(Solution.twoSum([2,3,6,7],9))** Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self,nums, target):
       nums=[]
       target=0
       i=0
       j=1
       ans=[]

       while i<len(nums):
           fir=self.nums[i]
           j=i+1

           while j<len(self.nums):
               sec = self.nums[j]
               # print(fir,sec)

               if fir+self.nums[j]==self.target:
                   ans=[fir,sec]
                   print(ans)
                   break

               j+=1
           i+=1
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but your function actually does nothing. It will just exit without entering the while.

Comment: you haven't set ```self.nums``` nor ```self.target``` so you'll more or less get an error.

Comment: @Ahmet why is that?

Comment: Why are you creating this pointless class? If you create a class, then you usually do it to create objects of that class, and then call methods on it. so `Solution().twoSum([2,3,6,7],9))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not directly do `print(Classname.something)`. You need to create an instance of the class (an object) like this:

```
test = Solution()
print(test.twoSum([2,3,6,7],9))
```

---

Edit: the function lacks a `return` statement. A typical function looks like this:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
    res = arg1*arg2
    return res
```

by default, functions return `None`, if there is no `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It supposes to return [3,6],but it returns None. Any ideas here?

Comment: @kri_5463 Yes you have to add `return ans` or something like that in the end of the function.

Comment: I have it under ***if***statement, and it worked last time w/ __init__ but it won't this time.

Comment: You have a `print()` under the if. But the function will still return `None`. I guess it will only reach the `print` statement under certain circumstances.